# Error 500 on HTTPS pages

Tags: php, apache, ssl

I have a website that has been working perfectly for several months. It is a joomla 2.5 site with a full, commercial SSL certificate from GoDaddy

Debian 7 64 bit server
Virtualmin
Hosted on Linode

No change to server, no new installs, nothing other than users browsing, and for some reason switching on errors does not reveal the problem / error.. just keeps showing the 500 page, and I cant find any error logs

Tried a fresh HTACCESS

The ONLY thing that has changed, the client has bought a new domain and just done a redirect / forward

If I browse the site without SSL, its perfect.

Can anyone give me a starting point for this perplexing 'out of nowhere' error

Thanks

Comment: go look at the server error logs. it'll have to details about what's causing the 500. without any details, we can NOT help you, other than "have you tried turning it off and on again"

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the error reporting, I am looking at the as the moment. I have no error logs to reference.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a SSL name mismatch error seeing that you are coming from a domain not listed in the certificate. Seeing as it is one of the requirements to set up a secure connection.

Comment: The primary domain is unchanged, and that is what I am using to access the system. Would a simple redirection to the site from another domain name break the primary site using the primary domain?

Comment: Are you able to connect using the old domain without the redirect?